# history.replaceState erases forward history. Replace current URL without erasing history?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

If you call `history.replaceState(null, null, newPath)`, all forward history is erased so that the new path is at the top of the stack.

Is there any way to replace or even append to the current URL WITHOUT erasing history, causing a popstate event, or causing a page reload?